# Saving settings in a class containing List<CustomClass>

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, application-settings

I'm trying to save some custom classes in XML format using a custom SettingsProvider which I found on GitHub (sorry but I can't find the link). But the output has special characters (E.g. `<`) converted (see below). The classes I'm trying to save are as follows:

```
[Serializable]
public class SoundClips
{

    //[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Items")]
    public List<SoundKeyBind> Items { get; set; }

    public SoundClips()
    {
        Items = new List<SoundKeyBind>();
    }

}

[Serializable]
public class SoundKeyBind
{
    //[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FilePath")]
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    //[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FileName")]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    //[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Volume")]
    public float Volume { get; set; }
    //[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("KeyBindText")]
    public string KeyBindText { get; set; }
    //[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("KeyBind")]
    public KeyPressedEventArgs KeyBind { get; set; }

    public SoundKeyBind (string FilePath, string FileName, float Volume, string KeyBindText, KeyPressedEventArgs KeyBind)
    {
        this.FilePath = FilePath;
        this.FileName = FileName;
        this.Volume = Volume;
        this.KeyBindText = KeyBindText;
        this.KeyBind = KeyBind;
    }

    public SoundKeyBind() { } //Required for serialization to work
}

[Serializable]
public class KeyPressedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    //[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Modifier")]
    public uint Modifier { get; set; }
    //[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Keys")]
    public Keys Key { get; set; }

    public KeyPressedEventArgs(uint modifier, Keys key)
    {
        this.Modifier = modifier;
        this.Key = key;
    }

    public KeyPressedEventArgs() { } //Required for serialization to work

}
```

The setting is configured as follows in the Settings Designer:

```
Name = "SoundBinds"
Provider = "MySettingsProvider"
Roaming = "True"
Scope = "User"
SettingTypeName="Sound_Board.SoundClips"
```

I'm saving the values like this:

```
class SharedVars
{
    //Excess code removed

    public static SoundClips keyBinds = new SoundClips(); //Stores key bind and sound file info

}

//Then elsewhere in the form
SharedVars.keyBinds.Items.Add(new SoundKeyBind("D:\\Sounds\\Example.mp3", "Example.mp3", 0.5f, "Shift + A", new KeyPressedEventArgs(4, Keys.A))); //Add an example key bind
Properties.Settings.Default.SoundBinds = SharedVars.keyBinds;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Here is the custom SettingsProvider:

```
namespace Sound_Board
{
    public sealed class MySettingsProvider : SettingsProvider, IApplicationSettingsProvider
    {
        private const string _rootNodeName = "settings";
        private const string _localSettingsNodeName = "localSettings";
        private const string _globalSettingsNodeName = "globalSettings";
        private const string _className = "MySettingsProvider";
        private XmlDocument _xmlDocument;

        private string _filePath
        {
            get
            {
                return Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath),
                   string.Format("{0}.settings", ApplicationName));
            }
        }

        private XmlNode _localSettingsNode
        {
            get
            {
                XmlNode settingsNode = GetSettingsNode(_localSettingsNodeName);
                XmlNode machineNode = settingsNode.SelectSingleNode(Environment.MachineName.ToLowerInvariant());

                if (machineNode == null)
                {
                    machineNode = _rootDocument.CreateElement(Environment.MachineName.ToLowerInvariant());
                    settingsNode.AppendChild(machineNode);
                }

                return machineNode;
            }
        }

        private XmlNode _globalSettingsNode
        {
            get { return GetSettingsNode(_globalSettingsNodeName); }
        }

        private XmlNode _rootNode
        {
            get { return _rootDocument.SelectSingleNode(_rootNodeName); }
        }

        private XmlDocument _rootDocument
        {
            get
            {
                if (_xmlDocument == null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        _xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                        _xmlDocument.Load(_filePath);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                    }

                    if (_xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode(_rootNodeName) != null)
                        return _xmlDocument;

                    _xmlDocument = GetBlankXmlDocument();
                }

                return _xmlDocument;
            }
        }

        public override string ApplicationName
        {
            get { return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Application.ExecutablePath); }
            set { }
        }

        public override string Name
        {
            get { return _className; }
        }

        public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)
        {
            base.Initialize(Name, config);
        }

        public override void SetPropertyValues(SettingsContext context, SettingsPropertyValueCollection collection)
        {
            foreach (SettingsPropertyValue propertyValue in collection)
                SetValue(propertyValue);

            try
            {
                _rootDocument.Save(_filePath);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                /* 
                 * If this is a portable application and the device has been 
                 * removed then this will fail, so don't do anything. It's 
                 * probably better for the application to stop saving settings 
                 * rather than just crashing outright. Probably.
                 */
            }
        }

        public override SettingsPropertyValueCollection GetPropertyValues(SettingsContext context, SettingsPropertyCollection collection)
        {
            SettingsPropertyValueCollection values = new SettingsPropertyValueCollection();

            foreach (SettingsProperty property in collection)
            {
                values.Add(new SettingsPropertyValue(property)
                {
                    SerializedValue = GetValue(property)
                });
            }

            return values;
        }

        private void SetValue(SettingsPropertyValue propertyValue)
        {
            XmlNode targetNode = IsGlobal(propertyValue.Property)
               ? _globalSettingsNode
               : _localSettingsNode;

            XmlNode settingNode = targetNode.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("setting[@name='{0}']", propertyValue.Name));

            if (settingNode != null)
                settingNode.InnerText = propertyValue.SerializedValue.ToString();
            else
            {
                settingNode = _rootDocument.CreateElement("setting");

                XmlAttribute nameAttribute = _rootDocument.CreateAttribute("name");
                nameAttribute.Value = propertyValue.Name;

                settingNode.Attributes.Append(nameAttribute);
                settingNode.InnerText = propertyValue.SerializedValue.ToString();

                targetNode.AppendChild(settingNode);
            }
        }

        private string GetValue(SettingsProperty property)
        {
            XmlNode targetNode = IsGlobal(property) ? _globalSettingsNode : _localSettingsNode;
            XmlNode settingNode = targetNode.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("setting[@name='{0}']", property.Name));

            if (settingNode == null)
                return property.DefaultValue != null ? property.DefaultValue.ToString() : string.Empty;

            return settingNode.InnerText;
        }

        private bool IsGlobal(SettingsProperty property)
        {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry attribute in property.Attributes)
            {
                if ((Attribute)attribute.Value is SettingsManageabilityAttribute)
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private XmlNode GetSettingsNode(string name)
        {
            XmlNode settingsNode = _rootNode.SelectSingleNode(name);

            if (settingsNode == null)
            {
                settingsNode = _rootDocument.CreateElement(name);
                _rootNode.AppendChild(settingsNode);
            }

            return settingsNode;
        }

        public XmlDocument GetBlankXmlDocument()
        {
            XmlDocument blankXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            blankXmlDocument.AppendChild(blankXmlDocument.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", string.Empty));
            blankXmlDocument.AppendChild(blankXmlDocument.CreateElement(_rootNodeName));

            return blankXmlDocument;
        }

        public void Reset(SettingsContext context)
        {
            _localSettingsNode.RemoveAll();
            _globalSettingsNode.RemoveAll();

            _xmlDocument.Save(_filePath);
        }

        public SettingsPropertyValue GetPreviousVersion(SettingsContext context, SettingsProperty property)
        {
            // do nothing
            return new SettingsPropertyValue(property);
        }

        public void Upgrade(SettingsContext context, SettingsPropertyCollection properties)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The `List` in the `SoundClips` class is having special characters converted to a 'safe' format. I.e. `<` becomes `&lt;` and it's including a second xml header, but I can't figure out why. Here is an example output of the settings file being generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings>
  <globalSettings>
    <setting name="SecondaryOutputDeviceID">-1</setting>
    <setting name="InjectMicOutputDeviceID">1</setting>
    <setting name="InjectMicInputDeviceID">0</setting>
    <setting name="PrimaryOutputDeviceID">-1</setting>
    <setting name="InjectMicEnabled">False</setting>
    <setting name="SoundBinds">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;
&lt;SoundClips xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;
  &lt;Items&gt;
    &lt;SoundKeyBind&gt;
      &lt;FilePath&gt;D:\Sounds\Example.mp3&lt;/FilePath&gt;
      &lt;FileName&gt;Example.mp3&lt;/FileName&gt;
      &lt;Volume&gt;0.5&lt;/Volume&gt;
      &lt;KeyBindText&gt;Shift + A&lt;/KeyBindText&gt;
      &lt;KeyBind&gt;
        &lt;Modifier&gt;4&lt;/Modifier&gt;
        &lt;Key&gt;A&lt;/Key&gt;
      &lt;/KeyBind&gt;
    &lt;/SoundKeyBind&gt;
  &lt;/Items&gt;
&lt;/SoundClips&gt;</setting>
  </globalSettings>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Special characters are being escaped because you're setting **InnerText** instead of **InnerXml**.

Here is an example showing the difference between the two [in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.innerxml(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3).

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I didn’t know InnerXml existed. Any idea why it’s still creating a second <?xml ...> header inside the “SoundBinds” node?

Comment: @Daniel, I'm not entirely sure. Has to be related to how `SettingsPropertyValue.SerializedValue` behaves. Things you could try are:
  - Set `targetNode.InnerXml` to empty string, `LoadXml()` from `SerializedValue.ToString()` and pass it to `targetNode.AppendChild()`;
  - SerializedValue property is probably `XmlNode` under the hood, so you could try to cast it to `XmlNode` instead of converting it to string and then loading XML from it;
  - If above options won't help you might have to add logic to remove <?xml ...> yourself.